# MailItem user property of type olDateTime showing by default 12/30/1899 value. How can we show empty instead?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I have created a user property on mailitem called "DueDate" i am setting default value null for this user property but when change the view in outlook & add the DueDate custom column on default view, it is showing "12/30/1899" value.

```
var prop = mailItemObject.UserProperties.Add("DueDate", Outlook.OlUserPropertyType.olDateTime, null, null);
prop.Value = null; //default value
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Null gets converted to 0, which in COM (it uses 8 byte floating point for date/time values) is 12/31/1899.
If you do not want to set a value, don't set it at all. Or set it to 1/1/4501 - that special date means "no data" in Outlook.

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround you may add a text (olText) user property instead (not date time). You can convert the date and time to a string and back in the code of your add-in. But in the view you will get what you need - empty strings.